# Задачка на SWI-Prolog: Найти родителя, который имеет ровно двух детей

Tags: prolog, дискретная-математика, swi-prolog

Имеется следующее дерево :

[image: Дерево отношений]

С помощью какого правила можно найти родителя, имеющего ровно двух потомков?

В результате пролог-система должна находить только Мэри, и только один раз.

Answer (score 1):

> С помощью какого правила можно найти родителя имеющего ровно два ребенка ? Пролог-система должна находить только Мэри, и только один раз.

С помощью правила (точнее, предиката) `has_children_num/2`.

В целом задача решается вызовом `goal/0`, смысл которого сводится к следующему:

Нет решений для цели "У Мзри есть два ребёнка и имеется другой родитель с двумя детьми"

```
 goal :-  findall( Parent,
               (    % Цель
                    has_children_num( mary, 2 ),
                    has_children_num( Parent, 2 ) ,
                     Parent \= mary
               ),
          Parents
          ),
          sort(Parents, []).

goal :- write( 'Нет (больше) решений для goal/0').

parent( mary, bob ).
parent( mary, ann ).
parent( jonh, bob ).
parent( bob,  liz ).
parent( bob,  paul ).
parent( bob,  sam ).
parent( paul, pat ).

has_children_num( Parent, N ):-
   findall( Child, parent( Parent, Child ), Children ),
   sort( Children, Children1 ),
   length( Children1, N ).

:- initialization( goal ).
```

Comment: Извините, я ошибся с деревом родственных связей.

Comment: @Ruslan OK вместо детей - потомки?

Comment: Если вы про задание, то нет. Пролог система должна так же находить только тех, у кого ровно 2 ребенка.

Comment: @Ruslan Вам подошёл ответ? Если да, то отметьте его пожалуйста, как принятый и, если можно, отдайте за него свой голос.